# How to parse Json POST request onResponse Stringrequest data

Tags: android, json, android-studio, post, android-service

I have some JSON response need to find a way to parse the token from the data

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Logged in successfully",
  "error_code": 0,
  "result": {
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJBdXRoIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJpYXQiOjE1NzEyODczNjEsImV4cCI6MTU3MTM3Mzg2MSwicGF5bG9hZCI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTAxIiwiY29tcGFueV9pZCI6IjEifX0.-BEWhUT762rkcdZCBG6gU8q52AhITUm_kPazh1Tsj78",
    "unique_id": "101",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last_name": "R",
    "user_groups_sites": [
      {
        "group_id": "6",
        "group_name": "Zonal Manager",
        "group_key": "zonal_manager",
        "sites": [
          {
            "site_id": "1",
            "site_name": "AAAA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group_id": "5",
        "group_name": "Auditor",
        "group_key": "auditor",
        "sites": [
          {
            "site_id": "1",
            "site_name": "AAAAA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, If you have not tried please try by your self first, If you find any problem when you are going to parse then we are ready to help you, Good Luck.

Comment: Show function from where you calling api.

Comment: public void parseData(String response) { try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); if (jsonObject.getString("error_code").equals("0")) {
String dataArray = jsonObject.getString("message");
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, dataArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,category_selection.class);
startActivity(intent);               
  }
           else {
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: Not this bro, retrofit call I said..ok below is the solution you will get your answer

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil bro I am using Volley library not retrofit

Comment: No issue, show volley call. The method where you call volley API

Comment: @AnkithPrakash Please update if(jsonObject.getString("error_code").equals("0")) with this -> if (jsonObject.getInt("error_code") == 0)        the problem is "error_code" is giving Int value and you are trying to get it by string that's why.please check it once and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sol 1:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
    String mToken = (String) myResponse.getString("token");
    Log.e("result", myResponse.toString());


    JSONArray userGroupsSites = myResponse.getJSONArray("user_groups_sites");

    for (int i = 0; i < userGroupsSites.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject sites = userGroupsSites.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e("actor", sites.toString());

        JSONArray getSiteObject = sites.getJSONArray("sites");
        JSONObject siteValue = getSiteObject.getJSONObject(0);
        Log.e("siteValue", siteValue.toString());

        String getSiteId = (String) siteValue.getString("site_id");
        String getSiteName = (String) siteValue.getString("site_name");
        System.out.println("Site Id: " + getSiteId);
        System.out.println("Site Name: " + getSiteName);

    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sol:2 Create a model class:

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    ResultData result;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ResultData getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ResultData result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public class ResultData {

        private String token;

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    }
}
```

API call should be:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Model> call, @NonNull Response<Model> response) {
        System.out.println(response.body().getResult().getToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Model> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

This will work fine.

Comment: bro I am using volley library

Comment: Ok show Volley call method, I will update my answer

Comment: public void parseData(String response) { try { JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); if (jsonObject.getString("error_code").equals("0")) { String dataArray = jsonObject.getString("message"); Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, dataArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,category_selection.class); startActivity(intent); } else { Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }   this is how iam calling now.

Comment: public void onResponse(String response) {
                   // Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("tessts11111t"+response,"tetstsststt");

                    parseData(response);
                }

Comment: not this bro...Ok try this one:
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
    String mToken = (String) myResponse.getString("token");
    System.out.println(mToken+"");

Comment: bro this worked but how can i get the other data as well?

Comment: which data do you want to get?

Comment: Sites/ site_id i have to get

Comment: Ok, the Answer is updated. It will work..Upvote if it helps so that others can use

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your json response by doing this first get the main json object and then get the first object called result .

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject resultObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("result");

String token = resultObject.getString("token");
```

Comment: send me your approach

Comment: Provide your method from where you calling api so that we can help you.